# Use this instead $scope on controller with provider

Tags: angularjs, angular-providers

I´m learning about Providers. On a common controller I would use

```
modu.controller("thecontrol", [function()
{
this.something = "Hello";
]});
```

and on the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="thecontrol as ctrl">
{{ ctrl.something }}
</div>
```

But... I´m trying to the the same with this code and, I really could not, even when I tried all the ways I "know".

Here´s the code...

**What I want?** Use THIS instead of $scope

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="showingName">

{{theNameIs}}

</div>



<script src="angular.js"></script>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.provider("showingName", function() {

    this.name = "Luis";

    this.$get = function() {
        var name = this.name;
        return {
            showName: function() {
                return name;
            }
        }
    };

    this.setName = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
});


myApp.config(function(showingNameProvider){
    showingNameProvider.setName("Juan");
});



myApp.controller("showingName", function($scope, showingName)
{
$scope.theNameIs = showingName.showName();
});


</script>
```

**And yes... It works, but I would like to know if it´s possible to do it with THIS.**

Thanks!

Comment: Do what, where, with "this"? Show an example of what you want.

Comment: Ok no I understand, you want this.theNameIs in the controller yeah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because when you don't name the controller, then the *{{ }}* has to be scope, since this and *$scope* can be different depending on the context. Say for instance in an ng-repeat, 1 controller yet essentially 2 scopes.

Name the controller like you did on the first, *ctrl as showingName*. Make the variable *this.theNameIs* and then use {*{ ctrl.theNameIs }}*

Also, personally I don't think you should name the controller and provider the same name, appreciate this is probably just an example.

More information on *$scope* and *this*:

['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot! Yes...! My problem was around the "name" of the controller. Thanks =D